# Preventing indexing of PDF files with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, googlebot

I have a ton of PDF files in different folders on my website. I need to prevent them from being indexed by Google using .htaccess (since robots.txt apparently doesn't prevent indexing if other pages link to the files).

However, I've tried adding the following to my .htaccess file:

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
Header append X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet"
</Files>
```

to no avail; the PDF files still show up when googling "site:mysite.com pdf", even after I've asked Google to re-index the site.

I don't have the option of hosting the files elsewhere or protecting them with a login system; I'd really like to simply get the htaccess file to do the job. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer, but I suppose you could use re-write rules to match the google user agent and redirect them to 404 page. Also, have you verified that visiting a PDF url on your site actually returns the X-Robots-Tag HTTP Header in the response? Lastly, when asking google to re-index, did you verify in your access_log that they actually did re-index you and hit those PDF urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in the comment made on another answer, I understand that
you are looking for removing indexed file/folder which is already done by `google`. You can temporary forbid it using following if you stop anyone accessing directly.

#### First, let me give you a workaround

after that I will let you know what you can do which will be taking bit longer time.

```
<Files "path/to/pdf/* ">  

    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

this way all files/folders inside the given directory will be forbidden to use in the HTTP method. This means you can only access it programmatically for sending in attachment or deleting or something but the user will not be able to view these.

You can make a script on your serverside which will access file internally and show file using parsing instead direct URL.(assuming data is critical as of now).

**Example**

```
$contents = file_get_contents($filePath);
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($filePath));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
echo $contents;
```

### Indexing vs Forbidding (No need of this now)

Preventing indexing basically prevent this folder/files to be index by google bots or search engine bots, anyone visiting directly will still be able to view the file.

In the case of Forbidding, no external entity/users/bots will able to see/access this file/folder.

If you have recently forbidden access of your `pdf` folder, it may still be visible to Google until Googlebot visits again on your site and find those missing or you mention `noindex` for that specific folder.

> You can read more about crawler rate on https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en
>
> If you still want these to remove, you can visit the Google search console and request the same. visit: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-report?pli=1

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to embed the PDFs on my site, so I will need to allow http access to them, just not from Google. This is also why a robots.txt solution won't work -- embedding the PDFs means that Google will index them anyway.

Which leaves me with "eader set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow", but for some reason, the pdfs are still visible in Google and have been so for a long time.

Comment: Hi, I have an updated answer, this will work for you. If you find useful, please do upvote the answer and accept it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just paste this in your htaccess file, use set instead of append

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Comment: I tried this after your suggestion, and requested that Google re-index my site. It has not helped -- all PDFs in my /PDF subfolder are still visible with a "site:mysite.com pdf" search.

Comment: How long did you wait? Google can be pretty slow on some of these things. Did you ever figure this out?